# Sharepoint 2013 app 404 error

Tags: iis, 404

I'm trying to deploy an app I got from the Windows Store in a new Sharepoint 2013 server.  I have a separate domain in DNS and can ping and resolve the app url.

However when I try to start the app from the Sharepoint home page I get a 404 error.  I downloaded Fiddler and it simply shows the 404 error.

Where can I look next to clear out this error?

Comment: I assume it's a SharePoint hosted app?

Comment: Not sure what "hosted" means in this context - it's an app in my onsite Sharepoint server - not Office 365, if that's what you mean.....

Comment: Did some comparisons - downloaded a different app from the Store and have the same result - but if I use an out-of-the-box apps it works just fine....

Comment: Found the answer - I had to create a new webapp using the Default Web Site in IIS to hold the downloaded store apps.  That got me to where I can now run the downloaded app.